# Crunch lots of files to generate stats file

Tags: php, algorithm, io

I have a bunch of files I need to crunch and I'm worrying about scalability and speed.

The filename and filedata(only the first line) is stored into an array in RAM to create some statical files later in the script.
The files must remain files and can't be put into a databases.

The filename are formatted in the following fashion :
Y-M-D-title.ext (where Y is Year, M for Month and D for Day)

I'm actually using glob to list all the files and create my array :
Here is a sample of the code creating the array "for year" or "month" (It's used in a function with only one parameter -> $period)

```
[...]
function create_data_info($period=NULL){
    $data = array();
    $files = glob(ROOT_DIR.'/'.'*.ext');
    $size = sizeOf($files);
    $existing_title = array(); //Used so we can handle having the same titles two times at different date.

    if (isSet($period)){
        if ( "year" === $period ){
            for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
                $info = extract_info($files[$i], $existing_file);
                //Create the data array with all the data ordered by year/month/day
                $data[(int)$info[5]][] = $info;
                unset($info);
            }
        }elseif ( "month" === $period ){
            for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
                $info = extract_info($files[$i], $existing_file);
                $key = $info[5].$info[6];
                //Create the data array with all the data ordered by year/month/day
                $data[(int)$key][] = $info;
                unset($info);
            }
        }
    }
    [...]
}

function extract_info($file, &$existing){
    $full_path_file = $file;
    $file = basename($file);

    $info_file = explode("-", $file, 4);

    $filetitle = explode(".", $info_file[3]);
    $info[0] = $filetitle[0];

    if (!isSet($existing[$info[0]]))
        $existing[$info[0]] = -1;
    $existing[$info[0]] += 1;
    if ($existing[$info[0]] > 0)
        //We have already found a post with this title
        //the creation of the cache is based on info[4] data for the filename
        //so we need to tune it
        $info[0] = $info[0]."-".$existing[$info[0]];

    $info[1] = $info_file[3];
    $info[2] = $full_path_file;
    $post_content = file(ROOT_DIR.'/'.$file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $info[3] = $post_content[0]; //first line of the files
    unset($post_content);

    $info[4] = filemtime(ROOT_DIR.'/'.$file);

    $info[5] = $info_file[0]; //year
    $info[6] = $info_file[1]; //month
    $info[7] = $info_file[2]; //day
    return $info;
}
```

So in my script I only call create_data_info(**PERIOD**) (**PERIOD** being "year", "month", etc..)

It returns an array filled with the info I need, and then I can loop throught it to create my statistics files.
This process is done everytime the PHP script is launched.

---

My question is : is this code optimal (certainly not) and what can I do to squeeze some juice from my code ?
I don't know how I can cache this (even if it's possible), as there is a lot of I/O involved.

I can change the tree structure if it could change things compared to a flat structure, but from what I found out with my tests it seems flat is the best.

I already thought about creating a little "booster" in C doing only the crunching, but I since it's I/O bound, I don't think it would make a huge difference and the application would be a lot less compatible for shared hosting users.

Thank you very much for your input, I hope I was clear enough here. Let me know if you need clarification (and forget my english mistakes).

Comment: You're not clear and neither is the code. Remove the code that is not relevant to the question and try to explain better what should be happening.

Comment: I rewrote my question, hope it's more clear this time.

Comment: If you are adding the data not that often and calling create_data_info quite often than you can think of creating cache files for each __PERIOD__. Don`t think the C booster will help, because glob is already using libc.

Comment: Yep I was thinking about that but don't know how :/. I know about caching for a DB but nothing about caching each __PERIOD__ info into a file.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you should use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) instead of glob function. When it comes to scandir vs opendir vs glob, glob is as slow as it gets.

Also, when you are dealing with a large amount of files you should try to do all your processing inside one loop, php function calls are rather slow.

I see you are using unset($info); yet in every loop you make, $info gets new value. Php does its own garbage collection, if thats your concern. Unset is a language construct not a function and should be pretty fast, but when using not needed, it still makes whole thing a bit slower.

You are passing $existing as a reference. Is there practical outcome for this? In my experience references make things slower.

And at last your script seems to deal with a lot of string processing. You might want to consider somekind of "serialize data and base64 encode/decode" solution, but you should benchmark that specifically, might be faster, might be slower depenging on your whole code. (My idea is that, serialize/unserialize MIGHT run faster as these are native php functions and custom functions with string processing are slower).

My answer was not very I/O related but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Hi @Mikk, 
thank you very much for your answer. 

Your comments are helpful thank you, I will change my code from your input.

The $existing is passed as a references because I need to modify it in the 
extract_info() function but can't return mulitple values.
So I went with a references allowing me to read/write the $existing array.
But maybe it's better to return an array containing the info array and the existing array ?

Also, what do you mean by "serialize solution" ? I don't understand how that would work :/.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear about my thoughts concerning serialization. I was thinking that you might concider serializing your data (array consisting of Y-M-D-title.ext), than base64 encode it and setting it to a file name. Afterwards you could retrieve all data with just one line -> $info_file = unserialize(base64_decode($file)); I'm not even sure it is faster, might run slower instead, but I'm too lazy to benchmark that atm.